# How do i set SmbSessionFactory to stop encoding the question mark when building the url string connection to samba?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, uri

I am trying to use SMB support of spring boot, and i created a bean with SmbSessionFactory like this.

`

```
@Bean
    public SmbSessionFactory smbSessionFactory() {
        SmbSessionFactory smbSession = new SmbSessionFactory();
        smbSession.setHost("myHost");
        smbSession.setPort(445);
        smbSession.setDomain("myDomain");
        smbSession.setUsername("myUser");
        smbSession.setPassword("myPassword");
        smbSession.setShareAndDir("myShareAndDir");
        smbSession.setSmbMinVersion(DialectVersion.SMB210);
        smbSession.setSmbMaxVersion(DialectVersion.SMB311);
        return smbSession;
    }
```

`
but myPassword has a question mark (?), and when the bean is creating the string url connection to samba, it uses UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath, that encodes questin mark, how do i tell SMB support to not enconde the question mark?

Answer (score 0):

Please, raise a GH issue so we will revise that logic in the `SmbConfig.getUrl()`.

Right now, as a workaround, you can extend that `SmbSessionFactory` and override its `createSession()` method to implement your own way to build that `SmbSession`.